pgxpool.ConnectConfig does not recognized and caouses build error
I have used the ConnecConfig function to create a pool. However, I am not satisfied with building it at the code below.
Compiler message: ConnectConfig not declared by package pgxpool
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
)

~
func NewConPool() pgxpool.Config {
    c, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(config.GetString("pgx.constr"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("database configuration could not be read, %w", err))
    }
    c.MaxConns = config.GetInt32("pgxpool.maxConns")
    c.MinConns = config.GetInt32("pgxpool.minConns")
    c.MaxConnLifetime = time.Duration(int32(time.Second) * config.GetInt32("pgxpool.maxConnLifetimeSec"))
    c.MaxConnIdleTime = time.Duration(int32(time.Second) * config.GetInt32("pgxpool.maxConnIdleTimeSec"))
    c.HealthCheckPeriod = time.Duration(int32(time.Second) * config.GetInt32("pgxpool.healthCheckPeriodSec"))
    c.ConnConfig.ConnectTimeout = time.Duration(int32(time.Second) * config.GetInt32("pgxpool.connectTimeoutSec"))
    pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), c)  //<-this line
    return *pool
}
~

Solved,

I have been tracking v4 documents, ConnectConfig changed to NewWithConfig at v5. 

v5 documents link: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool#hdr-Creating_a_Pool



Hmm I have just awared that i have tracked worng version's documents. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool#hdr-Creating_a_Pool is the correct one for v5, and uses NewWithConfig instead of ConnectConfig.
